# Avoid duplicate data on Time Series Insight / EventHub

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-timeseries-insights

I'm using Time Series Insight that is consuming events from EventHub. I just saw that we have some duplicated data. Is there a way to avoid the store of duplicate data on TSI or even on EventHub?

Comment: I cannot speak for TSI, but Event Hubs has an at-least-once delivery guarantee.  It is not possible to completely avoid duplication.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.